# .htaccess to secure admin directory in mvc architecture

Tags: .htaccess, security, model-view-controller, administration

I am trying to make a site with mvc structure. I have this :

- www/

  - blog/

    - app/

      - admin/

        - controller/
        - model/
        - view/
      - config/
      - front/

        - controller/
        - model/
        - view/
    - assets/
    - images/
    - libs/
  - portfolio /

I have a first .htaccess at the root (www/) for Gzip compression and stuff.
I have a second .htaccess for my blog (in www/blog/) with my very basic redirection system :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#QSA permet de garder les paramètres GET et les ajouter à la suite
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?p=$1 [QSA]
```

The file index.php in www/blog/ parses the url and uses the right controllers like this :

```
//****************************************************

include_once(APP_f.controller/controller.class.php');
$controlF = new ControleurF();

include_once(APP_b.'controleur/controleur.class.php');
$controlB = new ControleurB();


if (isset($_GET['p'])&&(substr($_GET['p'],0,4)== 'admin')) {
//on est dans l'admin
    $lapage=explode('/',$_GET['p']);
    if (!empty($lapage[1])) {$pp = $lapage[1];} else {$pp="index";}

    if (!isset($pp) OR $pp == 'index')
    { 
        $ctrl = "home"; $p = $ctrl;
    } else { 
        $params = explode('/',$pp); 
        $ctrl = $params[0]; $p = $ctrl;
        if (isset($params[1])) { 
            if ($params[1]<>"") {$p = $params[1];} 
        }   
    }

    $c=$controlB->load($ctrl);
    include_once($c);

}else{
//on est en front
    if (!isset($_GET['p']) OR $_GET['p'] == 'index')
    { 
        $ctrl = "home"; $p = $ctrl;
    } else { 
        $params = explode('/',$_GET['p']); 
        $ctrl = $params[0]; $p = $ctrl;
        if (isset($params[1])) { 
            if ($params[1]<>"") {$p = $params[1];} 
        }   
    }

    $c=$controlF->load($ctrl);
    include_once($c);
}

//****************************************************
```

Everything works fine but i am having trouble understanding how i could secure my admin folder with .htaccess/.htpasswd
Is there a way to do something like that in www/blog/.htaccess :

```
<Directory admin>
AuthUserFile "/home/foobar/www/blog/.htpasswd"
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
AuthName "Admin"
AuthType Basic
Require valid-user
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a way : use sessions with php
http://www.apprendre-php.com/tutoriels/tutoriel-14-les-sessions.html

Answer (score 0):

The Directory directive can only be used in server configuration or virtual host files. It cannot be used in htaccess files. It is described in [Apache Directory Directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#directory).

To password protect a directory using htaccess, you have to enter the following in .htaccess file:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Files"
# (Following line optional)
AuthBasicProvider file
AuthUserFile "/usr/local/apache/passwd/passwords"
Require user rbowen
```

The above commands will password protect the folder containing the htaccess file. The command: `htpasswd -c /usr/local/apache/passwd/passwords rbowen` generates a password for the user rbowen. It is described in [Apache Authentication and Authorization](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/auth.html)

Comment: Thank you Nadir for your answer. Is there a better way than using htaccess to protect/secure the admin folder with a password in this kind of MVC architecture ?

Comment: Syl, the htaccess password protection uses Basic or SHA-1 encryption. Both these methods of encryption are weak and easy to decrypt. It is recommended to use htaccess password protection over SSL connection. Another option for securing the admin area is to implement a custom secure login scheme based on user name and password